# Deploy to a Webserver with GIT

Tags: git, web-deployment, continuous-deployment

I am posed with a problem, too much information and no definitive answer. What I want is simple.

I use GIT and I commit changed to Bitbucket, great.
I want these changed pulled down to my web servers ( IIS and a Rackspace FTP server via cloudsites)

A client that can automate this as a lot of the setups I have seen required a lot of configuration and setup time per project that I do not have time to manage as we create microsites quite often and doing this per project would be a pain.

Happy to use a service or tool that is paid.

Answer (score 0):

Every deployment tool will need some kind of configuration. Some more, some less. It will depend on your needs and features the tool provides.

Based on the needs you have presented, I believe [deploybot](https://deploybot.com/) may be satisfying. It is build to be intuitive and easy to configure. You can have a deployment running in 15 minutes. It is a paid product with a [monthly subscription](http://support.deploybot.com/article/1028-plans-and-pricing), but as you stated this is not going to be a problem.

I don't use it as my deployment tool, but I have already tried it and it is pretty straight forward.

Comment: If you're recommending a service, I think it is good to mention that it's commercial software with [pricing](http://support.deploybot.com/article/1028-plans-and-pricing).

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply but stating the obvious "some will require more of less config" isn't helpful. Also I can google and find Deploybot. Iw ould like to know what you are using and how you find it rather than mentioning something else